# Why does Enterprise Connect exit immediately?

Tags: network, smb, active-directory

Attempts to restart Enterprise Connect do not result in showing its icon or menu.

Answer (score 1):

Using the command line in the Terminal app and running the application from there with an option attempting to show a list of options I was able to mount the share.  It persisted after pressing Ctrl+C.

```
$ /Applications/Enterprise\ Connect.app/Contents/MacOS/Enterprise\ Connect --help
2019-02-17 12:14:34.871 Enterprise Connect[38321:1060864] mounting shares is done
```